# Separate formatting, same line

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically, I want to be able to merge these two lines onto just one line. They should keep their individual properties.

```
<div><a href="boardfoot/woodcalc.php" target="_blank"><b>Board Foot Calculator</b></a></div>
<p onClick="openClose('a1'); openClose2('a3'); openClose2('a2'); openClose2('a4');" style="cursor:hand; cursor:pointer"><span style="color: #808080;">[Details]</span></p>
```

Hopefully this is possible somehow.

Comment: You should use `span` if you want to change things inline, since it is a standard inline element. Changing the `p` to `span` will probably fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<span><a href="boardfoot/woodcalc.php" target="_blank"><b>Board Foot Calculator</b></a></span>
    <span onClick="openClose('a1'); openClose2('a3'); openClose2('a2'); openClose2('a4');" style="cursor:hand; cursor:pointer"><span style="color: #808080;">[Details]</span></span>​​​​​​​
```

Comment: thanks @vector, I don't know how I didn't notice that on paste

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really be using that `<p>` tag if you don't want to start a new line

Comment: he shouldn't be using that div tag eithre

Comment: unless he wants to change it to `display: inline` or `inline-block`

Comment: It depends why div and p elements were chosen in the first place. If there are solid reasons for choosing them, then using display:inline or display:inline-block is fine; if there's no particular reason to use those tags though, then the better solution would be to change the tags. Otherwise you're just covering up a mistake rather than fixing what caused them to be displayed on two lines in the first place. Without knowing that, both answers ("change the elements" and "use display:inline") are equally correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:inline` css property, also with current tags.

```
<div style="display:inline;">•&nbsp;<a href="boardfoot/woodcalc.php" target="_blank"><b>Board Foot Calculator</b></a></div>
<p onClick="openClose('a1'); openClose2('a3'); openClose2('a2'); openClose2('a4');" style="cursor:hand; cursor:pointer; display:inline;"><span style="color: #808080;">[Details]</span></p>
```